# Unselectable select option that triggers select collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to enhance an existing `<select>` tag with an additional *«See more...»* row that, when selected, displays some GUI control. When user clicks on *«See more...»* I need that:

1. Current selected `<option>` is preserved
2. Additional row can't be selected
3. Drop-down closes

My first attempt fails #1 and #2:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $("select").each(function(){
    var $more = $("<option>See more...</option>")
      .on("click", function(){
        alert("Put your fancy AJAX dialogue here");
      })
      .appendTo($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Choose &laquo;See more...&raquo; for more options:</p>
<select>
  <optgroup label="America">
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option selected value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kinddom</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

If I add a *disabled* attribute to *«See more...»* row then it fails differently depending on the browser (Firefox keeps the drop-down open, Chrome won't process onclick handler at all):

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $("select").each(function(){
    var $more = $("<option>See more...</option>")
      .prop("disabled", true)
      .on("click", function(){
        alert("Put your fancy AJAX dialogue here");
      })
      .appendTo($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
[disabled] {
  font-style: normal;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Choose &laquo;See more...&raquo; for more options:</p>
<select>
  <optgroup label="America">
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option selected value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kinddom</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does #3 mean? You mean event handling?

Comment: What exactly would you like to do.

Comment: @serkandemirel0420 Not sure whether you tried the "Run code snippet" buttons but I've just realised that second snippet only seems to work on Firefox. In Firefox, the alert shows but the drop-down remains open. In e.g. Chrome you can't even click.

Comment: @ramvinoth I simply need to run JavaScript code when user clicks on the "See more" option, without modifying the currently selected option and without strange side effects.

Comment: In my case, what you said happens on the first snippet/firefox, not the second one. Second snippet is same on Firefox and Chrome. It does not propagate any event. That is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I store the previous value in oldValue and then if it is "See more..." I restore the old value:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var oldValue;
  $("select").on('focus', function () {
       oldValue = this.value;       
    }).change(function () {
       if (this.value=='See more...') {
          $("select").val(oldValue);
       }
       oldValue = this.value;       
    }).each(function(){
    var $more = $("<option>See more...</option>")
      .on("click", function(){
        alert("Put your fancy AJAX dialogue here");
      })
      .appendTo($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Choose &laquo;See more...&raquo; for more options:</p>
<select>
  <optgroup label="America">
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option selected value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kinddom</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .disabled {
        color: #808080;
    }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("select").each(function() {
            var $more = $("<option class='disabled>See more...</option>");
            $(this).append($more);
        });


        var options_sel_idx = 0;

        $("select").on("change", this, function(event) {
            if ($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).hasClass("disabled")) {
                alert("a");
                this.selectedIndex = options_sel_idx;
            } else {
                options_sel_idx = this.selectedIndex;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  $("select").each(function(){
    var $more = $("<option value='preserve'>See more...</option>")
      .prop("readonly", true)
      .appendTo($(this));
  });

var previousState = "";
 $("select").on('focus', function () {
       previousState = this.value;       
    }).change(function(e){
 if($(this).val() == "preserve"){
     $("select").val(previousState);
     alert("Put your fancy AJAX dialogue here");
    }
     previousState = this.value;  
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="select">
  <optgroup label="America">
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option selected value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kinddom</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this save the old value with global variable on  `click` event .passing the ajax function in the `onchange` event

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("select").each(function() {
    $("<option value='extra'>See more...</option>").appendTo($(this));
  });
  var old;
  $("select").on('click', function() {
    old = $(this).val();
  })
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'extra') {
      //do stuff
      console.log("Put your fancy AJAX dialogue here");
      $(this).children('option').eq($(this).val(old).index()).prop('selected', true);
    }

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Choose &laquo;See more...&raquo; for more options:</p>
<select>
  <optgroup label="America">
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option  value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kinddom</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- The overall `disabled` idea is not browser-compatible (Chrome won't catch click events on it).
- The simplest approach (tracking value changes manually) appears to be the best.

After some refinements my final code looks like this:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
 $("select").each(function () {
  var $select = $(this)
   .append(
    $("<option>See more...</option>").addClass("see-more")
   )
   .on("change", function () {
    var $selectedOption = $select.find("option:selected");
    if ($selectedOption.hasClass("see-more")) {
     $select.val(selectedValue);
     alert("Put your fancy AJAX dialogue here");
    } else {
     selectedValue = $selectedOption.val();
    }
   });
  var selectedValue = $select.find("option:selected").val();
 });
});
```

```css
.see-more{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Choose &laquo;See more...&raquo; for more options:</p>
<select>
  <optgroup label="America">
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option selected value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kinddom</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```